# Mule thread pool size cap

Tags: java, multithreading, mule

I am trying to set a thread pool size to a number greater than the number of cores of the machine I'm testing my Mule app on.

```
<vm:connector name="persistent" doc:name="VM">
   <receiver-threading-profile
       maxThreadsActive="64"
       poolExhaustedAction="WAIT"
       threadWaitTimeout="-1"/>
   <vm:queue-profile maxOutstandingMessages="5000">
       <default-persistent-queue-store/>
   </vm:queue-profile>
</vm:connector>
```

Eventually, what I see is that Mule caps the number of threads to the number of cores of my machine. Even If I try to set the default pool size in a general configuration element, I still get the same limitation.

```
<configuration doc:name="Configuration">
    <default-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="64" maxThreadsIdle="32"/>
</configuration>
```

This is what happens (my machine has 4 cores)

```
INFO  2014-11-11 11:12:22,023 [[App-1.0].persistent.receiver.03] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Order 21036
INFO  2014-11-11 11:12:22,025 [[App-1.0].persistent.receiver.01] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Order 21037
INFO  2014-11-11 11:12:22,030 [[App-1.0].persistent.receiver.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Order > 6 21038
INFO  2014-11-11 11:12:23,040 [[App-1.0].persistent.receiver.04] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Order 21040
INFO  2014-11-11 11:12:23,040 [[App-1.0].persistent.receiver.03] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Order 21039
INFO  2014-11-11 11:12:23,041 [[App-1.0].persistent.receiver.01] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Order > 6 21041
INFO  2014-11-11 11:12:23,043 [[App-1.0].persistent.receiver.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Order 21042
INFO  2014-11-11 11:12:24,060 [[App-1.0].persistent.receiver.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Order < 3 27
INFO  2014-11-11 11:12:24,061 [[App-1.0].persistent.receiver.03] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Order 24
INFO  2014-11-11 11:12:24,062 [[App-1.0].persistent.receiver.01] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Order > 6 26
INFO  2014-11-11 11:12:24,063 [[App-1.0].persistent.receiver.04] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Order 23
INFO  2014-11-11 11:12:25,081 [[App-1.0].persistent.receiver.04] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Order > 6 29
INFO  2014-11-11 11:12:25,083 [[App-1.0].persistent.receiver.01] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Order < 3 28
INFO  2014-11-11 11:12:25,090 [[App-1.0].persistent.receiver.03] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Order > 6 30
INFO  2014-11-11 11:12:25,092 [[App-1.0].persistent.receiver.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Order 31
INFO  2014-11-11 11:12:26,099 [[App-1.0].persistent.receiver.04] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Order > 6 32
INFO  2014-11-11 11:12:26,103 [[App-1.0].persistent.receiver.03] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Order 33
INFO  2014-11-11 11:12:26,103 [[App-1.0].persistent.receiver.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Order < 3 34
INFO  2014-11-11 11:12:26,105 [[App-1.0].persistent.receiver.01] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Order 35
INFO  2014-11-11 11:12:27,118 [[App-1.0].persistent.receiver.03] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Order < 3 41
INFO  2014-11-11 11:12:27,119 [[App-1.0].persistent.receiver.04] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Order > 6 40
INFO  2014-11-11 11:12:27,122 [[App-1.0].persistent.receiver.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Order < 3 42
INFO  2014-11-11 11:12:27,125 [[App-1.0].persistent.receiver.01] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Order 43
```

How do I actually increase the receiver thread pool size to 64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's another parameter called *numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers* which is somehow hidden. I couldn't find it anywhere in the Mule doc website, not even in Dossot's book. The following configuration did the trick for me:

```
<vm:connector
    name="order.vm.connector"
    createMultipleTransactedReceivers="true"
    numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers="64" >

    <receiver-threading-profile
        maxThreadsActive="64"
        poolExhaustedAction="WAIT"
        threadWaitTimeout="-1" />

    <vm:queue-profile maxOutstandingMessages="4096">
        <default-persistent-queue-store />
    </vm:queue-profile>

</vm:connector>

<vm:endpoint
    exchange-pattern="one-way"
    name="order.vm.endpoint"
    path="order.vm"
    connector-ref="order.vm.connector" />
```